# What is the saying in the Goonies just before they pop through into the treasure room?

Tags: the-goonies

On the pirate ship, Andy sets off a trigger and a trap door opens on the ceiling revealing some text just before the treasure room.  The kids don't even mention it.  Does anyone know what it says just before they break through it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**It's the Spanish verse on the map from the beginning.**

When they find the map, Mouth translates the verse (which oddly enough [rhymes in English](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/21244/why-do-the-instructions-rhyme-in-english) too):

> *"Ye intruders beware.
>
>   Crushing death and grief,
>
>   Soaked with blood,
>
>   Of the trespassing thief."*

The [script](http://goonies1632.free.fr/goon.pdf) verifies that the verse on the boards is the very same one from the map (see page 122). And though the one on the boards is hard to read, upon comparing the two, they do seem to match.

[image]

Comment: And another mystery solved.... by Skynet; +1.